# Printing csv through printer with python

Tags: python, csv, printing, writer

I want to output csv file with python. I have gone through below code and it is working well with .txt file but I am unable to print csv through it.

```
import os
import tempfile

filename = tempfile.mktemp(".txt")

open (filename , "w").write ("Printing file")

os.startfile(filename, "print")
```

Actually I want to print a csv file that had been already created, there will be no need to write and create new file then print it out.

Edit: From print I meant hardcopy print through printer

Comment: What do you mean by "well defined csv"? As in it prints out with aligned rows / columns?

Comment: csv that had already rows and columns data in it.

Comment: This is too broad/vague, and off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the content of a `csv` you can try this:

```py
import csv

file_path = 'a.csv'


with open(file_path) as file:
    content = csv.reader(file)
    for row in content:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Sorry, if I am not able to correctly write my problem, but I want to print csv in a hardcopy through printer

Answer (score 0):

I was talking about printing csv file as hardcopy with python code.

```
def printing():
        #reading from csv writing in txt
        with open("CSV_files//newfile.txt", "w") as my_output_file:
            cs = pd.read_csv("CSV_files\\attendance.csv",header=None,index_col=None)
            with open("CSV_files//attendance.csv", "r") as my_input_file:
                [ my_output_file.write(" | ".join(row)+'\n') for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]
        my_output_file.close()

        #reading from file and storing into reader and converting into string as .write() takes string
        strnew = ""
        with open('CSV_files//newfile.txt',"r") as f:
            reader = f.read()
            strnew = reader
            
        #for checking
        with open('CSV_files//print.txt',"w") as f:
            f.write(strnew)
        
        #printing
        filename = tempfile.mktemp("attendance.txt")#creating a temp file

        open (filename , "w").write(strnew)

        os.startfile(filename, "print")
        messagebox.showinfo("Print","Printing Request sent successfully!")
```

For more info:
[github project link](https://github.com/MidhaTahir/Smart_NEDIANS/blob/master/Smart_NEDIANS%20(PROJECT).ipynb)